# Converting seconds into hours only using Ruby in-built function - except the days

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4

In Rails, I am trying to convert seconds into hours only. But coincidently function gives something else.

```
For example - Second = 164580
Output like : 45:43:0
```

After some interval like 24 hours, it converts into day as well. I am trying to use any Ruby inbuilt function to get total hours only.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want to use `Time.at` or are you looking for a generic way to convert seconds into hours?

Comment: No. I googled a lot but I dnt find anything. So I tried Time.at It is not compulsary to use this

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Now that I see what you're looking for, I offer this:

```
def seconds_to_hms(sec)
  [sec / 3600, sec / 60 % 60, sec % 60].map{|t| t.to_s.rjust(2,'0')}.join(':')
end
```

Edit: Another option, even more concise:

```
def seconds_to_hms(sec)
  "%02d:%02d:%02d" % [sec / 3600, sec / 60 % 60, sec % 60]
end
```

Sample output;

```
seconds_to_hms(164580)
=> "45:43:00"
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use a simple method like this:

```
def seconds_to_hours(seconds)
  seconds / 3600
end
```

There are 60 seconds in a minute, and 60 minutes in an hour. So if you divide seconds by `60*60`, which is 3600, and then round it down, you will get the hours.

Comment: Actually I am trying to search any ruby function rather than writing function. I have done with function but I am wishing for ruby function. Thanks

Comment: May I ask why you want an internal Ruby function to use for this?

Comment: Internal Ruby Function is quite tested with every scenario. So I am trying for that.

Comment: I honestly don't think you need a well-tested internal method for this, but in any case, you can write a couple simple tests that would cover the scenarios you will be using this for. Apart from that, unfortunately I don't know an internal method for this.

Comment: Plus One - Thanks alot ... I will try as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 6):

If you would like to only show hours as output you can use this function:

```
Time.at(236).utc.strftime "%H"
```

Value "%H:%M:%S" stands for hours:minutes:seconds

You can read more about it here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone/strftime

Beside that - function Time is limited only to 24 hours. So you cannot count more than that value.

Comment: Please refer the question. I am asking the total hours if I increase the number of seconds like 23600000

Comment: Oops ... its a limit then what be the option to count that value.

Comment: You have to write a function, that divides your input by 3600 as it was mentioned by user 'jrg'.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the crude but simplest implementation to convert seconds to (x hours y minutes z seconds:

```
module Utils
  class TimeUtil
    def self.convert_to_h_m_s(seconds:)
      seconds = seconds.to_i
      _hours = seconds / 3600
      seconds = seconds % 3600
      _minutes = seconds / 60
      _seconds = seconds % 60
      str_arr = []
      str_arr << "#{_hours} hours" if _hours > 0
      str_arr << "#{_minutes} minutes" if _minutes > 0
      str_arr << "#{_seconds} seconds" if _seconds > 0
      str_arr.join(" ")
    end
  end
end
```

With a small tweak you can get just the hours.

Answer (score -1):

```
Time.at(23600).utc.hour
```

Should give you just the hour, no?

Comment: ya but what about Time.at(23600000).utc.hour give 3 hours

Comment: Ah. You want the total number of hours and not "Time".  Just divide by 3600, no?

Comment: Yes ..  Total number of hours :(

Answer (score -1):

After the suggestion of @hattenn, I am posting the function.

```
def convert_second_into_hours(calculated_seconds)
  hours = calculated_seconds/(60*60)
  remaining_seconds = calculated_seconds - ( hours*60*60 ) 
  minutes = remaining_seconds / 60
  seconds = remaining_seconds - ( minutes * 60 )
  puts "#{hours}:#{minutes}:#{seconds}"
end
convert_second_into_hours(164580)
```

output :

```
irb(main):118:0> def convert_second_into_hours(calculated_seconds)
irb(main):119:1>  hours = calculated_seconds/(60*60)
irb(main):120:1>  seconds = calculated_seconds - ( hours*60*60 )
irb(main):121:1>  minutes = remaining_seconds / 60
irb(main):122:1>  seconds = remaining_seconds - ( minutes * 60 )
irb(main):123:1>  puts "#{hours}:#{minutes}:#{seconds}"
irb(main):124:1>end
=> :convert_second_into_hours
irb(main):125:0>convert_second_into_hours(164580)
45:43:0
=> nil
```