# How to convert seconds in readable format ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I wanted to convert `111.700 seconds to readable format like this 1:51.7`,

Have checked this https://gist.github.com/shunchu/3175001, however still not sure how can i achieve the expected result.

Please can someone give me direction on this?

TIA

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting seconds into hours only using Ruby in-built function - except the days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28908214/converting-seconds-into-hours-only-using-ruby-in-built-function-except-the-day)

Comment: The gist you've liked to *pretty much* answers your question, so what about it exactly are you finding problematic? Are you stuck on how to add milliseconds into the format? Or how to remove leading zeros? Or are you asking someone to explain *how does it work*?

Comment: You can read more about the options for time formatting in the official documentation, for example, [here](https://apidock.com/ruby/Time/strftime). Critically, I think the formatting option you're looking for is `%L`.

Comment: @TomLord seconds 111 is fine, but getting the milli seconds .700 is something i am stuck on

Comment: @Manav Did you check the link I shared above, and/or try anything with the `%L` hint I gave? Something along the lines of `Time.at(t).utc.strftime("%M:%S.%L")`, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

If just minutes, seconds and milliseconds suffice then this may be enough:

```
puts 111.700.divmod(60).join(":")
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe @Tom Lord has already given a few pretty great options in the comments.

Also, @Arctodus has linked to an already given answer that does what you ask with the slight exception of milliseconds.

And I agree with Tom's answer as its simpler, and very ruby-like.

However, none seems to just exactly give what you asked in your original question, so even though I believe ideally the output should also denote something for the hours, here's what you asked for:

```
def seconds_to_human(sec)
  "%d:%.2f" % [ sec / 60 % 60, sec % 60]
end

seconds_to_human(111.700) # => 1:51.70
```

If you wanted hours too it'd just be a small change:

```
def seconds_to_human(sec)
  "%d:%d:%.2f" % [ sec / 3600, sec / 60 % 60, sec % 60]
end
seconds_to_human(111.700) # => 0:1:51.70
```